# Conky transparency isn't working in Mint 14

Tags: linux, laptop, linux-mint, transparency, conky

I've setup conky on my laptop installation of linux mint 14 (cinnamon), conky works except for the font transparency. I'm using:

```
xftalpha 0.5
```

in .conkyrc. But whichever value I use, the transparency doesn't change. I've also tried changing the own_window_type. Doesn't make any difference unfortunately. Other people with similar setups report that it works for them. Can anyone guide to where the problem is?

I guess I shouldn't post my complete conky configuration, it's maybe a little too much. But the most important parts are:

```
xftfont sans:size=10
use_xft yes
xftalpha 0.5
update_interval 1.0
own_window yes
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
own_window_type desktop
double_buffer yes
no_buffers yes
```

Comment: Has it got something to do with my theme settings, or did I disable compositing in some way? Because my transition effects still show (switching between workspaces etc.)..

Comment: Also, conky disappears when I minimize windows, or press Ctrl + Alt + D.

Comment: @slm,  It's the latest version from the mint 14 software manager. So I'd say 1.9.0

Comment: So the window is transparent, but the fonts are not then, correct?

Comment: @slm, yeah that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure you are not using any `${font}` or `${color}` commands in the TEXT section of your `.conkyrc`. The transparency seems to break if you specify font options in any way other than the `xft` commands in the options section. You also need to specify the default color and a few more options, try this:

```
alignment top_right
update_interval 1.0
default_color 000000
default_outline_color 000000
default_shade_color 000000
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_value 50
own_window yes
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
own_window_type desktop
use_xft yes
xftfont sans:size=60
xftalpha 0.2
double_buffer yes
no_buffers yes

TEXT
THIS IS TRANSPARENT!
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the code you posted works. What's weird though is that it doesn't work for the color I would like to use (pure white, #FFFFFF). Any ideas why that is?

Comment: Also, from your answer I deduce that with this solution it isn´t possible to use mutiple font sizes (with transparency)?

Comment: @samuel i couldn't get it to work with white no. Same goes for font sizes, i think it is because conky can either use the xft commands _or_ the conky font commands. I will try and find the thread i read this in.

Comment: @Samuel [this post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=951101#p951101) is where I got the idea to remove the `${font}` commands.